# How to acces a variable within an input definition

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events

I'm trying to add a `onclick` event to a newly dynamically created button inside a row cell in a table.

When I try to use the button this appears in the console:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined"

How can I access the variable `i` to put it inside the parenthesis of the `change()` function?

```
cell9.innerHTML ='<input type = "button"  value = "Edit" onclick="change(i)"/>';
```

*Edit:* So here is the entire function, `i` is a number that increases by 1 every time this function is used. The variable count is equal to the length of the table.

```
function save(){
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var i = count;
  

// Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the 1st position of the table:
var row = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
row.id="row-"+i;

// Insert new cells (<td> elements)in the"new" <tr> element:
var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
var cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
var cell8 = row.insertCell(8);
var cell9 = row.insertCell(9);
var cell10 = row.insertCell(10);
// Add some text to the new cells:
cell0.innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname2").value;
cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname2").value;
cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("cemail2").value;
cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("pnumber2").value;
cell4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("city2").value;
cell5.innerHTML = document.getElementById("address2").value;
cell6.innerHTML = document.getElementById("postalCode2").value;
cell7.innerHTML = document.getElementById("province2").value;
cell8.innerHTML = document.getElementById("cpwd2").value;
cell9.innerHTML ='<input type = "button"  value = "Edit" onclick="change(i)"/>';

   
}
```

Comment: Where is `i` coming from? Please post the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: i is the table's number of row. So my code is basically supposed to add a new row at the bottom of the table, in which there will be the button that I created.

Comment: wondering how you are getting "var i = count;" unique for each row. are you maintaining a global variable "count" in sync with row index?

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the `i` into element by **string concatenation** or **Template literals** like below

```
cell9.innerHTML ='<input type = "button"  value = "Edit" onclick="change('+ i + ')"/>';
```

or

```
cell9.innerHTML =`<input type = "button"  value = "Edit" onclick="change(${i})"/>`;
```